# How to run ajax call in background after some particulate time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show alert message after some perticulate time as 'Do you want continue?' 
If user say yes then ajax call must be run in background otherwise cancel the ajax call.
So please tell me how I can place time condition in ajax call response?

Comment: ajax calls usually run in the background

Comment: Browsers don't support background tasks.

Answer (score 0):

In technical terms it called as Long Polling request.. its something like this

```
function longPolling()
{
    $.ajax({
        //..... your ajax configurations like url, type, dataType...etc
        success: function(data){
            // your code  for handle success response
           setTimeout(function(){
                    longPolling();
                },5000) // call again after 5 seconds
        },
        error: function(xhr){
            //  your code  for handle error response
           setTimeout(function(){
                    longPolling();
                },5000) // call again after 5 seconds
        }
    };
});

longPolling();// call where ever you need
```

I hope it help to you

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout() function in javascript or jquery

Answer (score 0):

```js
var time = 5000;
setTimeout(function() {
  if (confirm('Do you want continue?')) {
    var root = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

    $.ajax({
      url: root + '/posts/1',
      method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  } else {
    // Do nothing!
  }

}, time)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's not that easy to decipher what the original poster wants, but your code is working fine, _and_ possibly doing what is asked for. I would suggest replacing `5000` with `1000`, or maybe even `700`. (The asker didn't specify a time.)

Comment: since OP didn't specify, kept it open as a variable. line 1 can be changed to what fits your use case best. Anyways, this is so old- happy to see ppl looking at it 5 years after. Among my first posts, I think :)

Answer (score 0):

What i understood from your question is that the ajax call will be made before you ask the user "whether you would like to continue or not" correct?

And i believe you wanted to make sure the user want to wait if the ajax call is taking long time?

if this is the case you just set a flag on user press "no" and just abort the ajax call

```js
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqXHR object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
});

//when user pressed no call the below function if the ajax is not completed
jqxhr.abort()
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
window.setTimeout(function () {

if (confirm('Do you want continue?')) {
    // Do some ajax?
} else {
    // Do nothing!
}

}, 5000);
```

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Comment: my friend, "ajax call must be run in background". your code will execute in UI thread.The right answer is, browsers don't support background tasks.